# Create gradient bar with angled side in CSS3

Tags: css

I'm trying to create this gradient filled box that has an angled right side in CSS and failing.  Is this possible?

[image: CSS Gradient - Illustrated]

The box needs to be sitting over an image so the right angle needs transparency.

Comment: Try this link. maybe it will help you http://cssglobe.com/angled-content-mask-with-css/ . And as for the gradient this should help http://gradients.glrzad.com/

Comment: Sitting over an image, its probably impossible, or at least I don't know how to do it. Your going to have to use an image for your blue gradient box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/QFUKU/2/), using @psu's suggestion of an angled content mask. Tested in: IE9/10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

In this case, the inner mask is skewed rather than rotated, which seemed simpler.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="outer-mask">
        <div class="skewed-mask">
            <div class="gradient"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: #ddd url(//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Background_repeat_unit.png) repeat-y -10px top;
}
.outer-mask {
    position: absolute;
    left: 75px;
    top: 45px;
    width: 330px;
    height: 110px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.skewed-mask {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 330px;
    height: 110px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
         -o-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
            transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
}
.gradient {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 330px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #234e7b;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #234e7b, #0d2951);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #234e7b, #0d2951);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #234e7b, #0d2951);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #234e7b, #0d2951);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #234e7b, #0d2951);
}
```

Bear in mind, this won't work for IE8 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [here, fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/mDB2h/) You can just fill in the gradient, and then adjust the `border-right` and `border-left` values along with the `left` value to adjust the shape of the angle.

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    background: blue;
}
div:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 260px;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 101px solid white;  // Make this say red instead of white to see whats going on
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Here's <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/mDB2h/1/">an update</a> that ads the gradient to your "shape"

Comment: @goin_13 Your link is broken.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/mDB2h/1/

Comment: Thanks, the issue with this is I need it transparent so it can be over an image.  I should have specified that.  I updated my link: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8852047/border.jpg

Comment: @kekona yes, you should've specified that.